# Google Web Toolkit Autobeans

Tags: java, gwt, reflection, autobean

Due to curiosity, I checked how `autobeans` are generated. I found it uses `sun.misc.ProxyGenerator` class to generate `autobean` `proxies` and that it uses `reflections`. But I do not understand, how does it work on client-side. Are those methods that use `reflections` compiled to `javascript`? Does it mean that I can use reflections myself on the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxy instances are only used on the server, in a real JVM, where reflection works. You are correct that GWT code cannot use general reflection.

To generate them on the client, a GWT Generator is used instead. This does all of the reflection while the GWT Compiler is still running, and so is in a real JVM, and creates new classes that implements your autobean interfaces and factories.

The `com.google.web.bindery.autobean.gwt.rebind.AutoBeanGenerator` class is mostly responsible for this work, and the contents of the `com.google.web.bindery.autobean.gwt.rebind.model` package (and, to a degree, `com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared`) assist in this work.

Comment: Thanks! Checked in debugger autobean implementation classes, they sure do not use proxies on the client!